# How do I check if last character of a string equals to "a" in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

For example:

I want to get the text/word by user and if this word's last character is "a" I want to change this "a" to "b"...How should i have to write this code?

```
let getText = txtWord.text

if

......
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to check if the last char is `"a"`.

If so just drop the last char and append the new one.

```
var text = txtWord.text

if text.characters.last == "a" {
    text = String(text.characters.dropLast()) + "b"
}
```

Comment: You could also do in-place alteration within the `if` e.g. `text.replaceRange(text.endIndex.predecessor()..<text.endIndex, with: "b")`

Answer (score 5):

swift 4:

```
let abc:String = txtWord.text
var newABC:String!
if abc.suffix(1) == 'a'{

   newABC = abc + "b"
   print("Done")
}
```